# Vue JS taking input dynamically inside v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, v-for

Hi I am trying to taking input in this fashion:

```
itemPrices: [{regionId: "A", price: "200"},{regionId: "B", price: "100"}]
```

As the user presses add button new input fields get added. 
For this I have taken an empty array=> `itemPrices: [],` inside vue app data.

Now Inside table element I have this code:

```
<vs-tr v-for="n in num" v-bind:key="n">
  <vs-td
    ><vs-input
      v-model="itemPrices[n].regionId"
      placeholder="Region Name"
    /></vs-td>
    <vs-td>
      <vs-input
        placeholder="price"
        v-model="itemPrices[n].price"
      />
    </vs-td>
  </vs-tr>
```

Here 'num' is just an integer which decides how many rows should be there. But this is not working... What is a possible solution for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you set `num` as `itemPrices` array length:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      itemPrices: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    num() {
      return this.itemPrices.length
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.itemPrices = [...this.itemPrices, {regionId: "", price: ""}]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuesax@4.0.1-alpha.16/dist/vuesax.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuesax@4.0.1-alpha.16/dist/vuesax.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <vs-button @click="addItem">add</vs-button>
  <vs-tr v-for="(n, i) in num" :key="n">
    <vs-td>
      <vs-input
        v-model="itemPrices[i].regionId"
        placeholder="Region Name"
      />
    </vs-td>
    <vs-td>
      <vs-input
        placeholder="price"
        v-model="itemPrices[i].price"
      />
    </vs-td>
  </vs-tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure “num” is a filled array I think you can use the following code:

```
<vs-tr v-for="n in num" v-bind:key="n">
            <vs-td
              ><vs-input
                v-model="n.regionId"
                placeholder="Region Name"
            /></vs-td>
            <vs-td>
              <vs-input
                placeholder="price"
                v-model="n.price"
              />
            </vs-td>
          </vs-tr>
```

Since n is a representation of each instance inside your array.

Although, you should provide you JS code as well. This way people here get a better understanding of what is going on. For example, I can’t see what “num” looks like.

Comment: num is just a number... which decides how many rows need to be there

Comment: Then why don’t you use the v-for directly on your array?

Comment: v-for=“(item, index) in array” :key=“index”

Comment: Because it is an empty array and I need to fill it with inputs dynamically.

Comment: Ok. But if the array (itemPrices: []) is an empty array and you are trying to v-model your data to e.g. itemPrices.regionId it will fial. Because there is no property regionId in your empty array, right?

Comment: Yes, there is no property regionId  in my empty array

Comment: Then Vue doesn’t know where to v-model the given data. You could use an @submit handler, prevent the default submit functionality. Then extract the data from the fields. Save the data to an object and push this object to your array.